# How to use GUNIT with MAVEN?

Tags: java, maven-2, antlr, gunit

Given a Maven project generated by :

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.antlr \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=antlr3-maven-archetype \
  -DarchetypeVersion=3.2 \
  -DgroupId=com.yourcompany \
  -DartifactId=yourproject \
  -Dversion=yourversion \
  -Dpackage=com.yourcompany.package.path
```

cf : http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Building+ANTLR+Projects+with+Maven

which have such architecture  :

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        |-- antlr3
        |   |-- com
        |   |   `-- yourcompany
        |   |       `-- package
        |   |           `-- path
        |   |               |-- TLexer.g
        |   |               |-- TParser.g
        |   |               `-- TTree.g
        |   `-- imports
        |       `-- Ruleb.g
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- yourcompany
                    `-- package
                        `-- path
                            |-- AbstractTLexer.java
                            |-- AbstractTParser.java
                            `-- Main.java
```

by adding maven-gunit-plugin to the pom :

```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-gunit-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.2</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>maven-gunit-plugin</id>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>gunit</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
```

Where should be GUNIT files ?

**update (already)** :

I am not talking about Junit integration (but, if it's the only way, i will sure go for this one).

Comment: Didn't you read the docs? (http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/gUnit+-+Maven+Integration)

Comment: I did (even this one). This is not for maven-gunit-plugin, and you can probably get better result with  org.codehaus.mojo:gunit-maven-plugin as for junit integration.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant pieces from the source tell me it uses ${basedir}/src/test/gunit. For the files it either uses the private variable includes or **/*.testsuite if includes is undefined. It seems that maven-gunit-plugin is unable to handle JUnit integration with 3.2.